# Setting up testing of an Ember boilerplate on JSBin.com

Tags: ember.js, jsbin

I'm learning Ember basics running the code online in the awesome http://ember.jsbin.com/ code fiddling service. It provides a basic boilerplate of an HTML file, a CSS file and a JS file.

I wonder how can use it to run unit tests of my Ember app.

My goal is to be able to run the app and the tests from a single JSBin instance. I imagine switching between the two modes by adding/removing `?test` in the URL, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i gave it another try and found that official Ember Guides contain a demo of how it can be done in JSBin.com!

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jesuyeri/20/edit?js,output
Relevant guides page: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's highly unlikely that this will work. Unit tests should be run by cmd.

Comment: a lot of testing platforms have browser interfaces, you should investigate maybe Karma with QUnit. It might be easier than you think if you're already using build tools like Gulp or Grunt

Comment: I don't have trouble setting up Ember tests. I just want to do test-covered Ember snippets to post on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry to withdraw the answer acceptance, but i found that you can actually do what i was asking for, and it's right in the official guides. See my answer below and don't forget to upvote! :D